# Adobe PDF Reader redownload PDF files after hide\show the PDF document in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe, browser-cache

I faced really a strange problem with Adobe PDF reader and Firefox browser. I used embed element to display the pdf in html and put this embed tag into a div element.

Now on html page, I have two buttons to show/hide the div element. After I hide and show the div, the pdf is downloaded again although Firefox already cached it (I viewed Firefox's cached by using about:cache).

This problem doesn't happen with IE browser. I tried to search information about this problem but no luck. Does anyone face this problem before?
I used FF6 and Adobe PDF reader 10.

Here is what I captured from Firebug

```
ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date    Fri, 19 Aug 2011 06:55:47 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    application/pdf
Content-Length  466982
Connection  Close
```

Comment: Interesting question - I guess it has to do with the way the browser and the PDF plugin work together. What caching headers are getting sent along with the document, can you catch them (e.g. using Firebug) and post them?

Comment: Here is what I saw in FirebugServer 
ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date Fri, 19 Aug 2011 06:55:47 GMT
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
Cache-Control private
Content-Type application/pdf
Content-Length 466982
Connection Close

Comment: I edited my first post including the Response header captured from Firebug